# Axes labels as multiples of $\tau=2\pi$

Tags: plotting, labeling

When using Plot[], is it possible to have axes labeled with multiples of $\tau=2\pi$, **not $\pi$**?

This question is not a duplicate of ([Axes labels as multiples of $\pi$](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94606/axes-labels-as-multiples-of-pi#163544)). Replacing [Pi] with [Tau] doesn't help (when you define $\tau=2\pi$), as Mathematica seems to be hard-wired to label the axis with multiples of $\pi$. I want **the letter $\tau$ to be rendered**, not the number $2$ and the letter $\pi$. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not sound right to me:

> "... as Mathematica seems to be hard-wired to label the axis with multiples of "

You should always share code of what you have tried so people can find and explain your errors to you. Here is 2 different ways to approach labeling in your case:

```
Plot[Cos[x],{x,-5Pi,5Pi},Ticks->{Range[-6Pi,6Pi,2Pi],Automatic}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Cos[x],{x,-5Pi,5Pi},Ticks->{Table[{2Pi n,n ""},{n,-3,3}],Automatic}]
```

[image]

As @BobHanlon kindly noticed in the comments, `String` around "" is

1. a safety mechanism against "evaluating to numerical value" if  was assigned a value
2. a flexible construct to render more complex things for `Ticks` as `Style` can be applied, etc.

This is explained well in [the doc page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html).

Comment: I tried using \[Tau] (with a backslash at the front) but it didn't work. It seems that writing  does the job. Thanks.

Comment: @Vestoo - if you have previously given `\[Tau]` a value, the symbol `[Tau]` will never appear in the output since its value will always be substituted. That is why the string must be used for it to appear.